# Ideals in a ring as geometric objects?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, ideals, visualization

I am interested in learing about the possibility of (one-sided) ideals in a ring being repreented geometrically. In other words, about their status as geometric objects (after all, they can be dealt with in algebraic geometric, can't they?). Apparently, the so-called Nullstellensatz provides for that. Could anyone explain me the whole thing about ideals as geometric objects and the relation to Hilbert's theorem on zeros?

Comment: Since you ask about one-sided ideals, are you primarily interested in the non-commutative case?

Comment: @Takumi Murayama. Exactly. My primary interest is that of non-commutative scenarios. For practical and pedagogical reasons, I would prefer illustrations of right ideals rather than left ideals, but all of them are welcome.

Comment: The nullstellensatz is really a part of commutative algebra. Noncommutative geometry seems to be a different animal.

Comment: What I meant is that Hilbert's Theorem allows for the translation from ideals to geometry and viceversa. Non-commutative cases would ust be a specific sample of the whole, I guess......

Comment: No comments? :(

Comment: Nullstellensatz deals with the commutative case. There is no such theorem in the non-commutative case. Although there are some proposed notions of spectrum in the non-commutative case.

Comment: Forget about the theorem then. My question on geometrical representation is still relevant...

Comment: Any feedback on the geometric representation of ideals?